# Ocaml function wanting to take 2 arguments although just one is necessary?

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I'm trying to write a function that finds the longest running sub-list of increasing integers in a list.

This is what I have so far (very long variable names to help me understand it better):

```
let increasing list = 
  let rec aux inputList currentLongestList currentHighestList lastInsertedElement = 
    match inputList with
    | [] -> 
      if List.length currentLongestList > List.length currentHighestList then currentLongestList
      else currentLongestList
    | hd :: tl -> 
      if hd > lastInsertedElement then aux tl (currentLongestList @ hd) currentHighestList hd
      else aux tl currentLongestList currentHighestList lastInsertedElement
  in 
  aux list [] [] [min_int]
;;
```

My issue is that when this is entered, it says `val increasing : int list list -> int list = <fun>` implying 2 lists need to be passed where I only want one in the function? What am I doing wrong? Also, the function doesn't work if I take away the square brackets from `min_int`, even though I don't see why they're needed - what would I have to do to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inferred type informs you that the argument named `list` is a list of lists of integers. Let us understand why, step by step.

First, the type checker has unified the type `list` with the type of `inputList` because of your call to `aux` at the end of the function `increasing`.

Second, the head of the `aux` argument named `inputList` is compared with `lastInsertedElement` in the second case of `aux` pattern-matching. Since `lastInsertedElement` is of type `int list` because of your initial call to `aux`, the type induces that `inputList` has type `int list list`.

For your second question, "why the brackets seem needed around `min_int`?". Look at the expression "... @ hd". It implies that "hd" must be a list...

Comment: This is very useful, however I still can't completely understand why increasing would have to take int list list. What could I modify in the function so it just takes int list?

Comment: Your code is written as if `hd` were a list. But the head of a list is a single element from the list. E.g., the head of [1;2;3] is `1` (*not* `[1]`). Something else strange is that the name `lastInsertedElement` sounds like it should be an int (an element of your input list). But the code is treating it also as a list. This could just be an issue of naming.